# A demonic reputation requires a demonic notification?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

It just happens to me that my reputation become demonic, thus equals exactly 666!

Any chance to make a notification for this rare situation?

[image: Scary]

Comment: as awesome as it is you had 666 rep.... seems a bit too much to ask the stack overflow coders to create something for that.

Comment: Your email is visible on your screenshot, if you're bothered by such things. If not... nothing to see here, please move along ;p

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be Christians or non-Christians who would be more "WTF?" upon receiving this notification.

Comment: it is just an easter egg suggestion.. don't take is so personal

Comment: Yes, let's have special notifications for all the numbers that may have a special significance to someone somewhere.

Comment: @Louis Hypothetically... "Congratulations, you have [1729](http://www-gap.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Quotations/Hardy.html) rep."

Comment: Counter proposal:  you get a notification when you have enough reputation to spell "unicorn" in binary.  I'm looking at you, Skeet.

Comment: Eh, a goofy badge if you manage to hit it exactly.  \

Answer (score 16):

There is in fact already a notification for when you reach 666 rep: you going on to meta to tell everybody about it!

No need for anything further.

Comment: Have an upboat. We just got notified